# Help finding recursive formula for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have struggle since yesterday and couldn't find a pattern for the following sequence:

1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 23, 31, 47

Can you see the pattern?

Comment: Observe the consecutive differences

Comment: I do see the difference, but no idea how to generate 1 1 2 2 4 4 8 8

Answer (score 1):

You’ve discovered that the first differences follow a nice pattern:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
a_n:&1&2&3&5&7&11&15&23&31&47\\
a_n-a_{n-1}:&&1&1&2&2&4&4&8&8&16\\
a_n-a_{n-1}:&&2^0&2^0&2^1&2^1&2^2&2^2&2^3&2^3&2^4
\end{array}$$

Now you want to reduce this to a formula of some kind. This can be done in several ways. The easiest is just to use a two-part definition:

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
a_{n-1}+2^{(n-1)/2},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\\\
a_{n-1}+2^{(n-2)/2},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\;.
\end{cases}$$

There’s nothing wrong with this. If you really want a single formula, you could use the floor (or greatest integer) function:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}\;.$$

Or you could make use of the fact that $(-1)^n$ has two values, one for odd $n$ and one for even $n$; I’ll leave it to you to figure out how to make this work if you’re curious enough.